# How to find and replace a field column value in UNIX

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, string

I have file with the value say which is delimited with `|`

```
123-|aaa|bbb|123|123.0|123-|123.01-|-123.02|123.03-|aaa|bbb|123-|aaa-|-bbb|cc-cc|123.04-|aa123-|123.05-
```

I need to pick the column values which end with `-`, the column picked up should be a numeric value and then move the `-` to start of the value.

Comment: could you add an example, it a bit unclear what you want to do

Answer (score 3):

POSIXly:

```
sed ':1
     s/^\(.*|\)\{0,1\}\([0-9.]*[0-9][0-9.]*\)-\(|.*\)\{0,1\}$/\1-\2\3/
     t1'
```

Or with  `awk` in a more intuitive way:

```
awk -F '|' -v 'OFS=|' '{
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
    if ($i ~ /^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?-$/)
      $i = "-" substr($i, 1, length($i)-1)
  print}'
```

(that version is stricter in what it considers to be a *number*, the `sed` one would accept `1...2` as a number for instance).

On your input, that gives:

```
-123|aaa|bbb|123|123.0|-123|-123.01|-123.02|-123.03|aaa|bbb|-123|aaa-|-bbb|cc-cc|-123.04|aa123-|-123.05
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by anchoring the match to the beginning of the line or a separator. For example with a GNU sed extended regular expression:

```
sed -r ':a; s/(^|\|)([0-9.]+)-(\||$)/\1-\2\3/; ta' infile
```

Output:

```
-123|aaa|bbb|123|123.0|-123|-123.01|-123.02|-123.03|aaa|bbb|-123|aaa-|-bbb|cc-cc|-123.04|aa123-|-123.05
```

Comment: Hi Thor,
Executed with the follwing command it throws a error
sed -r 's/(^|\|)([0-9.]+)-/\1-\2/g' d1.txt
sed: illegal option -- r
Usage: sed [-n] [-e script] [-f source_file] [file...]

Comment: @MeghanaPrakash: This was tested with GNU sed. Which version of sed are you using?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: good point, I added a terminal anchor as well, thanks.

Comment: Hi Thor, it works now thank you very much :)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Interesting, this seems to be because of overlapping matches. It can be fixed by looping, as you have already found.

Comment: Hi Thor i have another issue here, if one of the columns has say |S55112-22|
it gets replaced as |-S5511222| which should not be caused,
we have to check after "-" sign if delimeter "|" exists only it should pick up and change

Comment: @MeghanaPrakash: Did you try with the latest version? I recently added an ending anchor as suggested by Stephane.

Comment: oops sorry missed it, it works now thank you :)